# What does " openURL:(NSURL *)url " do in facebook login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am a beginner in iOS development and I am integrating facebook login in my app using [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/)

In the whole project I can't understand what the following function does:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
}
```

This method will call after the user has `authorized` the app through `Safari` of the `Facebook` app.

```
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
```

Above line let `Facebook SDK` handle the login result and modify the login view accordingly.(It handles all login process)

```
openURL:(NSURL)url
```

- **url**

It is used to send request to server. As per Apple's documentation   it is resource to open. This resource can be a network resource or a file.

I think this explanation may help you to clear all your doubt

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This method simply allows your app to open URL of specified in facebook SDK or any other SDK you are using, You can read more about it here [application:openURL:options:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?preferredLanguage=occ)